# Trouble rendering two functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am having trouble with this code. The second function (`updateFeedbackRequestStatus`) does not return when I run it. The first function does run.

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
class PlayButton extends React.Component {

    play = () => {
        window.musicPlayer.play(this.props.song);
        this.updateFeedbackRequestStatus(this.props.feedback_id)
    };

    updateFeedbackRequestStatus = (id) => {
        const url = ['/label/feedback_requests', id,'listened'].join('/');
        $.post(url, {}, function (data, status) {
            $('#feedback-request-' + id + ' #give-feedback-button').show();
        });
    };

    render () {
        return <a onClick={this.play} className="m-song__trigger" />;
    }
}

export default PlayButton
```

Comment: Is this a react/javascript question? add those tags

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "does not run"?

Comment: it allows me to click play in the site but it doesn't pop up the update feedback button like it's suppose to.

Comment: This is a react question.

Comment: Add console.log statements in your `play` and `updateFeedbackRequestStatus` to determine where the failure is occurring. If you still can't figure it out, I would suggest creating a codesandbox environment so that we can get a look at how things are working together.

Comment: Ok, i added a console.log in both of them and they are both console loging. i think the issue is with the return statement.

Comment: Close the question when it's been solved.